# Does LG WebOS 3.5 support webdriver for QA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, webos, lg

I'm working on Javascript ( nodejs ). 
Using `selenium-webdriver` I'm able to automate on browser with local server but not on tv (LG WebOS 3.5).
How to connect with tv and automate my Apps file?

Answer (score 0):

I've had discussions with the WebOS developers at LG regarding testing.
Unfortunately, the only method of debugging on the TV directly is by using a serial cable and PuTTY (or equivalent software) ...
http://openlgtv.org.ru/wiki/index.php/Debug_mode_connection